# mercurial graft feature, can it copy?

Tags: mercurial

there is a new feature in mercurial 3, called 'graft' (graft to local).
it does a good job of moving a change-set to a different branch.

Is there a way to "COPY" a change-set to a branch?

I am interested in in moving stuff from the QA branch to the production branch, but I still need the code to reside in QA. So what I really want is a copy. I just found this and have only tried a few things, maybe it'll all become clear with some more tinkering and reading...

Does anyone have a better way of 'cherry picking' change-sets to move cross branch (or trunk)???

Answer (score 2):

Graft copies changesets, it doesn't move them. From `hg help graft` (emphasis mine):

> This command uses Mercurial's merge logic to *copy* individual changes from other branches without merging branches in the history graph. This is sometimes known as 'backporting' or *'cherry-picking'*. By default, graft will copy user, date, and description from the source changesets.